# How to get chart to ignore text/blank? - EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have a column in a table that has the following formula

```
=IF([@[JoBM]]>0; IF([@[JoBF]]>0;[@[Median1]]/[@[Median2]];"-");"-")
```

The column has looks something like this: 0.9, 0.84, - , - , 1.2, 0.93, 1.3, -

From this column I need to create a graph that ignores the "-". The "-" needs to be included in the table for visual purposes. Any ideas?

Comment: If you mean to drop those rows from both the x-axis and the values, how about filtering the column to hide the `"-"` rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try different things with the chart, depending on your version of Excel. Alternatively, you can alter the blank values to use the `NA` function.

To do that, try one of these methods that work for you:

- In the blank cell, type #N/A.
- In the formula bar for the blank cell, type =NA().
- If the cell range for the Line chart uses a formula to obtain values from a different cell range, and if you do not want the Line chart to plot 0 (zero), type the following formula in the formula bar:
  =IF(SUM(range)=0,NA(),SUM(range))